# Rewriting recursive function to iterative approach

Tags: python, recursion

How would you rewrite this python code without recursion?

```
def f(n):
   if n == 1:
       return 2
   elif n == 2:
       return 1
   elif n == 3 or n == 4:
       return n
 
   r1 = f(n-1)
   r2 = f(n-2)
   r3 = f(n-3)
   r4 = f(n-4)
 
   return (r1+r2+r3)/r4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may keep the initial condition, then use the values for `r1, r2, r3, r4` when `n=5`. Then iterate until you reach your `n`, by rotating the values and compute the next ratio

```
def f_vars(n):
    initial_values = [2, 1, 3, 4]
    if n <= len(initial_values):
        return initial_values[n - 1]

    r3, r2, r1, next_n = initial_values

    for _ in range(n - 4):
        r4, r3, r2, r1 = r3, r2, r1, next_n
        next_n = (r1 + r2 + r3) / r4

    return next_n
```

Using an array you can also achieve it, but lower performance

```
def f_array(n):
    initial_values = [2, 1, 3, 4]
    if n <= len(initial_values):
        return initial_values[n - 1]

    for _ in range(n - 4):
        initial_values.append(sum(initial_values[1:]) / initial_values[0])
        initial_values.pop(0)

    return initial_values[-1]
```

---

A few timing info

- `n=10_000_000` and `f_vars` takes about `2sec`
- `n=10_000_000` and `f_array` takes about `10sec`
- `n=29` and `f (recursive)` takes about `12sec`